# Rails 3 model with accepts nested attributes not updating children

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a model setup where a user can create a quiz with many questions and many answers on each question

The models look like this:

```
model Page < AR::Base

end

model Quiz < Page
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :allow_destroy => true
end

model Question < AR::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true
end

model Answer < AR::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

And my form looks like this:

```
= form_for @quiz do |f|

  f.fields_for :questions do |qf|
    # fields omitted, have fields for id, content, etc
    qf.fields_for :answers do |af|
      # fields omitted, have fields for id, answer, etc
  f.submit 'save'
```

Everything works wonderfully when I edit just the quiz or when I add new questions and answers, but when I edit existing questions and answers, the changes aren't persisted in the DB. I can see the correct nested parameters being sent into the controller and when inspected the @quiz after calling `update_attributes` it shows the updated questions and answers but they aren't being persisted after the page is updating.

I've never had this sort of issue before and am having trouble spotting the cause, can anyone share some insight?

Thanks!

As requested, controller code: (Quiz is an STI subclass of Page)

```
PagesController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @page = @section.pages.find(params[:id])

    if @page.update_attributes(params[@page.type.downcase.underscore])
      redirect_to online_course_section_pages_path(@online_course, @section), :notice => "Your page has been updated"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Found the problem was because of using `@page.type.downcase.underscore` instead of `@page.type.underscore.downcase` so update attributes was being passed nil instead of the actual data

Comment: Are you using attr_accessble in your model definitions?

Comment: nope, first thing i looked for

Comment: post source of your controller, that handles updating of the quiz

Comment: Is this a type issue perhaps? A Quiz accepts nested attributes, but you might trying to call "update_attributes" on a Page.

Comment: no because it works fine on create and update will update the attributes on the quiz object, but not any of the child elements

Comment: plus it is updating the quiz attributes just not any nested ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem was because of using @page.type.downcase.underscore instead of `@page.type.underscore.downcase` so update attributes was being passed nil instead of the actual data